# Rails okta exchanging an auth code for a token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, authorization, okta

I've had trouble finding documentation specific to rails that covers how to exchange an auth code for an access or id token. Most of the documentation supporting rails on Okta's website makes the assumption that the developer is using devise, which sort of abstracts away all the details.

Unfortunately, we don't use devise and we use HTTParty for requests. We use React on the front-end which currently implements a `oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect` component. Both react and the rails server run on localhost:3000.

The user is redirected to Okta's sign in form, and when they log in successfully, it then makes the callback to this `authenticate` function inside the `OktaAuthController` and returns the authorization code. Right now, I am successfully able to retrieve the code from `params[:code]` so there is no issue there.

However, when I try to make a request to exchange the code for a token, I get the following error:

{"errorCode":"invalid_client","errorSummary":"Invalid value for 'client_id' parameter.","errorLink":"invalid_client","errorId":"oaeD6KrI0qISLSsiOgCwVnysA","errorCauses":[]}

Below is the code from the controller:

```
def authenticate
    @code = params[:code]
    
    url = 'https://{{our_dev_url}}.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token'

    headers = {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'authorization': 'Basic MG9hY...',
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }

    @client_id = {{client_id_here}}
    @client_secret = {{client_secret_here}}

    data = {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: @code,
      client_id: @client_id,
      client_secret: @client_secret,
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/okta/callback',
    }

    response = HTTParty.post(url, headers: headers, body: data.to_json)
    puts response
  end
```

I'm trying to replicate the example shown on Okta's website. I've also tried Base64 encoding the client_id and client_secret since I've seen in other rails documentation that it was necessary, but I'm getting the same result regardless

https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/authcode/main/#request-an-authorization-code

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default/v1/token \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'authorization: Basic MG9hY...' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&code=P59yPm1_X1gxtdEOEZjn'
```

I've additionally tried Base64 encoding the client_id and client_url before making the post request, but I'm receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into different issues because it's requiring PKCE flow at the moment, but in case anyone finds themselves here via google, the resolution for my particular question is that the value for authorization should've been "Basic {{ encoded_auth }}"

where

```
encoded_auth = Base64(client_id:client_secret)
```

the code:

```
    @client_id = {{ client_id_here }}
    @client_secret = {{ client_secret_here }}

    @authorization = Base64.encode64("#{@client_id}:#{@client_secret}").gsub(/\n/, '')

    headers = {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'authorization': 'Basic ' + @authorization,
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }

    data = {
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': @code,
      'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:3000/okta/auth',
      'scope': 'openid'
    }
    response = HTTParty.post(url, headers: headers, body: data)
```

the rest of the code is the same as above